# Parameterizing a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, parameters

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JSON Array Test</h2>

<p id="outputtext"></p>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var arrayinput = {
    collection:[ 
{firstAttr:"XXXA",secAttr:"13156161",lastAttr:"01" }, 
{firstAttr:"XXXB",secAttr:"11153325",lastAttr:"02"  }, 
{firstAttr:"XXXC",secAttr:"14431513",lastAttr:"03"  },  
{firstAttr:"XXXC",secAttr:"13312163",lastAttr:"01"  }]};



var outputElement = document.getElementById("outputtext");

function arrayscanner(arrayvar, container, scanvar){
arrayvar.container.filter(function(item) {

  return item.lastAttr = scanvar;

    })};


var filteredArr = new Array();  
filteredArr = arrayscanner("arrayinput", "collection", "01");



for (var i=0; i<filteredArr.length; i++) {
outputElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", item.firstAttr + " " + item.secAttr + ", ");
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason this is not working.
The error message I get is:

```
 Element type "filteredArr.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I am trying to use the function to be reusable with parameters. 
I need to give the array name, the container name and the value I am scanning for to the function. 
The output can be just a one liner.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

To set the container as the object property, you can't use dot notation. Use bracket notation instead:

```
function arrayscanner(arrayvar, container, scanvar){
  arrayvar[container].filter(function(item) {

  return item.lastAttr = scanvar;

})};
```

Also, when you run the function, pass the actual array as a parameter, not a string with the name of the array. Lastly, you aren't returning anything from your `arrayscanner` function. It helps to troubleshoot your code as you write it, you shouldn't just keep writing more code if a small part doesn't work. I've added a couple `console.log`s to help show you where you could have pinned down these issues.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdwJKV

You'll notice that I located three different issues, and the code still doesn't actually append to the HTML. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to isolate the single issue that you are experiencing *yourself*. You should never post code with out knowing where it's failing.

Locating that single fail point is not only good for posting here, but also a critical programming skill.